# Is there any request parameter in browser request from browser in Active Directory that differentiate Active Directory Domain?

Tags: java, active-directory, active-directory-group, jakarta-ee

Is there any request parameter in browser request from browser in Active Directory that differentiate Active Directory Domain ?
Or anything that differentiate Active Directory Domain.

Code to print all request parameters-:

```
try 
{ 
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies(); 
    if (cookies == null) 
        cookies = new Cookie[0]; 
    for (int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) 
    { 
        log.warning(cookies[i].getName()+":\t"+cookies[i].getValue()+"\n"); 
    } 
    log.warning("Req URI :"+request.getRequestURI()); 
    log.warning("Request Protocol:"+ request.getProtocol()); 
    log.warning("Servlet path :"+ request.getServletPath()); 
    // log.warning("Path info: "+(util.HTMLFilter.filter(request.getPathInfo()))); 
    //log.warning("Query string:"+(util.HTMLFilter.filter(request.getQueryString()))); 
    log.warning("Content length: "+ request.getContentLength()); 
    //log.warning("Content type: "+(util.HTMLFilter.filter(request.getContentType()))); 
    log.warning("Server name: "+ request.getServerName()); 
    log.warning("Server port: "+ request.getServerPort()); 
    log.warning("Remote user: "+ request.getRemoteUser()); 
    log.warning("Remote address:"+ request.getRemoteAddr()); 
    log.warning("Remote host:"+ request.getRemoteHost()); 
    log.warning("Authorization scheme: "+ request.getAuthType()); 
    log.warning("Locale: "+ request.getLocale()); 
    //log.warning("The browser you are using is "+(util.HTMLFilter.filter(request.getHeader("User-Agent")))); 
    Enumeration en = request.getParameterNames(); 
    // enumerate through the keys and extract the values 
    // from the keys! 
    //while (en.hasMoreElements()) 
    //{ 
    //    String parameterName = (String) en.nextElement(); 
    //    String parameterValue = request.getParameter(parameterName); 
    //    log.warning(parameterName+":"+parameterValue+"\n"); 
    //} 
    //Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames(); 
    //while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) 
    //{ 
    //    String headerName = headerNames.nextElement(); 
    //    log.warning(headerName); 
    //    // log.warning("\n"); 
    //    Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaders(headerName); 
    //    while (headers.hasMoreElements()) 
    //    { 
    //        String headerValue = headers.nextElement(); 
    //        log.warning("\t" + headerValue); 
    //        // log.warning("\n"); 
    //    } 
    //} 
} 
catch(Exception e)
{ 
    ErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e); 
}
```

---

Comment: Are trying to do SSO with Active Directory?

Comment: i need to restrict perticular Active Directory Domain users from accessing applications.

Comment: How are you doing the authentication? Also post the code.

Comment: I am not doing authentication, fetching only request parameters.